# Why the velocity $v$ is taken as value and not as definition in special relativity equations?

Tags: special-relativity, velocity, coordinate-systems, inertial-frames

Why the velocity $v$ is taken as a value and the definition of velocity not applied on a relativistic equations?

---

The equations of time dilation and length contractions as we know are 
$$L = {L_0}{\left( {1 - {{{v^2}} \over {{c^2}}}} \right)^{{1 \over 2}}}$$
and 
$$\Delta t = {{\Delta {t_0}} \over {{{\left( {1 - {{{v^2}} \over {{c^2}}}} \right)}^{{1 \over 2}}}}}$$ 
Here, ${\Delta {t_0}}$ is time interval between two events, and ${L_0}$ is length in rest frame. An observer moving with velocity $v$ measures the time interval $\Delta t$ and the length $L$.

---

The velocity $v$ that I am using has some value and for some reason I take it as a value and do not apply the definition 
$$v = {{dx} \over {dt}} = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{\Delta t \to 0} {{\Delta x} \over {\Delta t}} = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{t \to {t_0}} {{x - {x_0}} \over {t - {t_0}}}$$
Velocity as I know is "change in displacement over change in time". Let's take length contraction equation, as the length contract there must be some variation for the end points of a rod (say) to move across a point, causing change in $v$. So, why I am not taking some relativistic equation of $v$ here in the equation. I feel, somehow there is some connection between length contraction, time dilation and this velocity. There must be something in this $v$ which is not factored in these equations.

Comment: Would the fact that $v$ represents the velocity of the moving frame (relative to a frame considered stationary) help see why it's a constant value?

Comment: @kyle the moving frame will have contraction, and the question remains the same.

Comment: The frame *doesn't* have a contraction, but objects within the two frames will have different lengths based on the relative speed of the moving vs stationary frame.

Comment: Even though a stationary observer will see an object as contracted, the front of that object will pass by him with the same velocity $v$ as the rear of that object.

Comment: @KyleKanos Why not? Isn't frame all about space-time?

Comment: @BillWatts Suppose I have a device which is capable of measuring ends of an object as it passes through a point. Also, suppose there are infinite number of rods with same lengths in a line. Now these rods are passing as I keep increasing the velocity. The goal is to measure speed of each rod as it passes by. The first rod will take some time to pass through the point but the last one with velocity c is just a point. Velocity measured has to be factored. Isn't it?

Comment: @BillWatts Rear passes by with same velocity as front, but how you have calculated your $v$ here? Please explain in terms of velocity definition.

Comment: You certainly don't measure the velocity using the body's length as you are implying.  Measure the velocity of one point on the body.  The front or the rear are the easiest to use.  Length contraction has no effect.

Comment: @RoopeshSingh You have two observers in the at rest reference frame along the line of flight of the object but separated by a set distance. Each observer notes the time the front of the object passes him.  Calculate the velocity from the difference in their observed times and their separation distance.  Length contraction plays no part whatsoever in the velocity calculation.

Comment: @BillWatts Why not? Consider a scenario you on a platform. Given train length how would you calculate velocity? Forget length, consider just a point moving in a space-time. The space-time in which it is travelling, how can I be sure about the space-time in my calculation hasn't gone under any change, when I am considering a possibility of very high relativistic velocity.

Comment: @BillWatts On the second comment, why are you assuming the space-time (relativistic) to act like a normal space-time?

Comment: Two observers at rest (no relativity) measuring the time it takes the front  of the object to traverse their separation.  If you are measuring the velocity by having a single observer compare the time difference between the front passing and the rear passing you are doing it wrong because you don't know the length of the object, and you can't know the length without already knowing the velocity.